# Error while launch with module and GXT4

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am trying to use the GXT4 in my GWT project but it gives me an error when i launch the app. I followed the GXT guide from their site and added the inherit in the module of my project but it gives me this error: **Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
                  [ERROR] Line 67: Unexpected element 'resource'
                  [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML**

PS I'm not using maven. What is wrong?

**My module**

```js
 <module rename-to='myproject'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <!--  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>-->
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> 
 <inherits name="com.google.maps.gwt.GoogleMaps" />
 <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
 
  <stylesheet src="reset.css" />
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<!--   <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/> -->   

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.myproject.project.client.Myproject'/>
  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

Comment: which version of GWT are you using ? GXT 4 requires at least GWT 2.7 and java 1.7

Comment: Check this: https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/getting_started/Versions.html

Comment: Ok thank you very much!

Comment: If you're jumping to GXT 4.0, using GWT 2.8.0-beta1 is good to use too.